# exe created by py2exe give error

Tags: python, py2exe

i have created an exe from py2exe. After successfully creating the exe, i got the following error when i run main.exe.

```
  File "_mssql.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "_mssql.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using pymssql module for sql server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure you include the module under the [options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) dictionary. I think it also needs a dll file called `ntwdblib.dll`. you can find that file and include it into your `setup.py`.

```
import os, pymssql
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
dll = []
dll.append(os.path.join(os.path.split(pymssql.__file__)[0], 'ntwdblib.dll'))
pyops = {"includes": ['decimal']}
setup(console=['app.py'], options={"py2exe": pyops}, data_files=dll)
```